# Is there a format like polyline6 but with altitude for API

Tags: line, rest, encoding

I develop a REST API and need to send/receive coordinates with their altitude.

For now we only needed latitude and longitude so we were using [Polyline6](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) to have an efficient way to transfer data.
Polyline6 is very efficient because it does two things : computes differential data, not the whole data, and then encode it.

Now, we need to add altitude data to the coordinates but Polyline6 does not support it. Transfering a large number of coordinates can take a long time and I would like to be as efficient as possible. I would like to avoid to transfer an array of [longitude, latitude, altitude] or to manually compress data with gzip and base64.

Do you know an alternative to Polyline6 which supports altitude, or any standard format which could fit to my need ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Comment: Cross posted here on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76884561/is-there-a-format-like-polyline6-but-with-altitude-for-api